# Sort hashtable before inserting into the HTML

Tags: html, powershell, sorting, hashtable, psobject

I am having an issue sorting the data before feeding the data into the HTML. I have tried multiple ways to sort the psobject, however, it is not sorting based off the LastRebootTime. I am trying to sort either the outputobject in the function:getRemoteServerInfo or trying to sort the @writeParams. Both aren't getting sorted.

```
$computername = $env:computername
$DateStamp = (Get-Date -Format D)
$FileDateStamp = Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd
$ScriptPath = Get-Location
$ReportFileName = "$ScriptPath\ServerPatchReport.html"
$ReportFileName2 = "$ScriptPath\ServerPatchReport-Unavailable.html"
$BGColorTbl = "#EAECEE"
$BGColorGood = "#4CBB17"
$BGColorWarn = "#FFFC33"
$BGColorCrit = "#FF0000"
$PendingRebootYes = "Yes"
$PendingRebootNo = "No"
$ReportTitle = "$ReportTitle"
$RunFrom = "This report was generated from $computername"
$Global:Servers = Get-Content servers.txt

# Create output file and nullify display output
New-Item -ItemType file $ReportFileName -Force > $null
New-Item -ItemType file $ReportFileName2 -Force > $null

<#==================================================
Write the HTML Header to the report file
==================================================#>
##HTML code

If ($Servers.count -gt 0) {
    Write-ToLogFile -Info "Starting remote job against $($Servers.count) servers"
    $RemoteJob = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock ${function:getRemoteServerInfo} -computername $Servers -AsJob
    $JobID = $RemoteJob.Id
    Wait-Job -Id $JobID -Timeout $JobTimeout | Out-Null
    $FailedServers = Get-Job -ID $JobID | select-object -expandproperty ChildJobs | Where-object {$_.State -ne "Completed"} | Select-object -expandproperty Location
    $CompletedJobs = Receive-Job -ID $JobID -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Foreach ($Server in $FailedServers) {
        writeUnavailableData $ReportFileName2 $Server
    }

    Foreach ($Server in $CompletedJobs) {
        $Server | Sort-Object -Property LastReboot -Descending
        #Write-Host $Server
        $writeParams = @{
            FileName = $ReportFileName
            Server = $Server.PSComputerName
            InstalledOn = $Server.InstalledOn
            KB = $Server.KB
            TaskTrigger = $Server.taskTrigger
            LastReboot = $Server.LastReboot
        }
        #$writeParams | sort-object @{Expression={$_[2]}; Ascending=$false}
        writeUpdateData @writeParams
    }

    Write-Host "Finishing report..." -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
    writeHtmlFooter $ReportFileName
}
<#==================================================
Function to write server update information to the
HTML report file
==================================================#>
Function writeUpdateData {
    param($FileName,$Server,$InstalledOn,$Domain,$KB,$OSType,$DataCenter,$taskTrigger,$LastReboot)
    Add-Content $FileName "<tr>"
    Add-Content $FileName "<td align='center'>$Server</td>"
    Add-Content $FileName "<td align='center'>$OSType</td>"
    Add-Content $FileName "<td align='center'>$Domain</td>"
    Add-Content $FileName "<td align='center'>$InstalledOn</td>"
    Add-Content $FileName "<td align='center'>$LastReboot</td>"
    Add-Content $FileName "<td align='center'>$KB</td>"


    # Color BG depending on $Warning and $Critical days set in script
    If ($InstalledOn -eq "Error collecting data")
    {
        $DaySpanDays = "Error"
    }
    Else
    {
        $System = (Get-Date -Format "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
        $DaySpan = New-TimeSpan -Start $InstalledOn -End $System
        $DaySpanDays = $DaySpan.Days
    }
    If ($InstalledOn -eq "Error collecting data" -or $DaySpan.Days -gt $Critical)
    {
        # Red for Critical or Error retrieving data
        Add-Content $FileName "<td bgcolor=$BGColorCrit align='center'>$DaySpanDays</td>"
        #Add-Content $FileName "</tr>"
    }
    ElseIf ($DaySpan.Days -le $Warning)
    {
        # Green for Good
        Add-Content $FileName "<td bgcolor=$BGColorGood align=center>$DaySpanDays</td>"
        #Add-Content $FileName "</tr>"
    }
    Else
    {
        # Yellow for Warning
        Add-Content $FileName "<td bgcolor=$BGColorWarn align=center>$DaySpanDays</td>"
        #Add-Content $FileName "</tr>"
    }
    Add-Content $FileName "<td align='center'>$datacenter</td>"
    Add-Content $FileName "<td align='center'>$taskTrigger</td>"
}



<#==================================================
Function for servers that are unavailable
==================================================#>
Function writeUnavailableData
{
    param($FileName,$Server)
    Add-Content $FileName "<tr>"


    Add-Content $FileName "<td bgcolor=$BGColorWarn align='center'>$server</td>"
}

<#==================================================
Function to write the HTML footer
==================================================#>
Function writeHtmlFooter
{
    param($FileName)
    Add-Content $FileName "</table>"
    Add-Content $FileName "<table width='75%' align='center'>"
    Add-Content $FileName "<tr bgcolor=$BGColorTbl>"
    Add-Content $FileName "</tr>"
    Add-Content $FileName "</table>"
    Add-Content $FileName "</body>"
    Add-Content $FileName "</html>"
}

function getRemoteServerInfo {
    #Create output object
    $OutputObject = New-Object PSObject

    #Fetch last reboot date / time
    $LastReboot =gwmi win32_operatingsystem | %{ $_.ConvertToDateTime($_.LastBootUpTime) }
    $OutputObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name LastReboot -value $LastReboot

    #Fetch patch info
    $session = [activator]::CreateInstance([type]::GetTypeFromProgID('Microsoft.Update.Session'))
    $searcher = $session.CreateUpdateSearcher()
    $totalupdates = $searcher.GetTotalHistoryCount()
    $remoteresult = $searcher.QueryHistory(0 , $totalupdates) | select-Object -First 1 | Select-Object Date, Title
    $OutputObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name remoteresult -value $remoteresult

    $Installed = $remoteresult.date
    $InstalledOn = $Installed.tolocaltime()
    $OutputObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name InstalledOn -value $InstalledOn
    $KB = $remoteresult.Title.Split('(')[1].split(')')[0]
    $OutputObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name KB -value $KB

    $OutputObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name tasktrigger  -value $taskTrigger

    $OutputObject
    }    
}
```

Comment: `foreach ($Server in $CompletedJobs |Sort-Object LastReboot){ ... }`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen
wow, that really worked. By sorting in foreach-loop, we are doing a presort? To be honest, I have never anything like it.

Comment: Well, it's the collection in `$CompletedJobs` that you want to sort, so... sort that?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - nice one!

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - can we do a multiple sort on that object? like, sort by computername, and then by Last reboot? I tried doing that by mentioning multiple objects. It doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's the items in `$CompletedJobs` that need sorting, pipe it to [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object) before entering the loop:

```
foreach ($Server in $CompletedJobs |Sort-Object LastReboot){ 
  #...
}
```

---

If you want to sort on multiple keys, just pass more property names to `Sort-Object`:

```
$CompletedJobs |Sort-Object PSComputername,LastReboot
```

You can also modify the direction of each, by using a property expression:

```
$CompletedJobs |Sort-Object PSComputername,@{Expression='LastReboot';Descending=$true}
```

Comment: Nope, the sort-object doesn't like that. I am still playing around with it.

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't like that" - are you getting an error?

Comment: I don't get any error, but it is sorting only by the first key. If i give, PScomputername, lastreboot, the sort happens only via PSComputerName

Comment: Does it change if you set `Descending=$false`?

Comment: it doesn't change. I am wondering if a Group-object should be used?